# Not Able to Access Google Cloud Composer Stable API Through Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-composer, google-vpc

I have a use-case i.e. to trigger cloud composer DAG from compute engine that does not have explicit external IP and all the traffic to the public internet is routed through Cloud NAT and in Cloud NAT we are using static IP so that it can be whitelisted in composer. I am using **curl** command to serve this purpose. Below is the command I am using to trigger the DAG.

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST "AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_URL/api/v1/dags/cf_test/dagRuns" -d '{"conf": {}}'
```

I am able to trigger the DAG with **Allow access from all IP addresses** is active in composer but whenever I am restricting the IPs through composer web server access control I am facing the below error even after whitelisting the Cloud NAT's static IP.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
<h2>Access is forbidden.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Just to debug, I have created a compute engine with dedicated external IP and I am able to trigger the DAG using the same DAG after whitelisting this VM's external IP.

Can someone please help me to sort this out?

Note: All the instances (composer and both the VMs are deployed under the same VPC and for testing, we have whitelisted both inbound and outbound traffic from any IP and any Port through the firewall rule.

Please let me know in case of any other details.

Comment: Are there any log errors generated by composer in Cloud Logging or Airflow specific logs?  The returned error to the Curl request (403) says forbidden ... but what we are looking to understand is "why" we were forbidden and I think we'll get that from the back-end logs.  I hear that we have allow listed what we "think" is the caller's IP address ... let's see if we can't think of a way to validate that what we think is the IP is actually the IP.

Comment: What kind of [NAT IP addressing](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/ports-and-addresses) have you configured your Gateway to use? Perhaps the external IP is changing if it's configured to be allocated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be caused by many reasons, these 3 are the most common ones:

**1. Authentication**

If you are using basic_auth with .Airflow 2.0, the `AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND` environment variable should be set to `airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth`. You will have to restart the webserver container. Then, you should be able to access all stable APIs using the cURL commands with `--user` option.

**2. API**

There is a configuration parameter that causes ALL requests to the API to be denied.
You can see this [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html?highlight=rbac#api-authentication), it is mentioned that you need to override the following Airflow configuration:

```
[api] auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all
```

to this code

```
[api] auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default
```

You can see this documentation about [Triggers DAG with Cloud Functions](https://ttps://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf).

**3.IP Address**

Validate that the correct IP address has access to the VPC and NAT. You can test this by removing access to each IP address and see which IP address gets an error.